# Query posts from two post formats within a category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been reading the [WP_Query Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) looking for a way to loop through all the posts that have the post format 'video' OR 'image', within a given category.

If this wasn't enough, this category is given by a variable `$catslug` (I need it to be this way).

I have only found ways of looping through one of the following

- image OR video
- image AND category
- video AND category,

but what I need is more complex, something like this:

`post-format-image` AND `$catslug`) OR (`post-format-video` AND `$catslug`)

Is it possible to do a `tax_query` within a `tax_query`?

Something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array($catslug)
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'post-format-image' )
            )
        ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array($catslug)
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'post-format-video' )
            )
        )
    ) 
); 
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Anyone knows any workaround or a hack to get this?
Perhaps I'm just thinking the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually a good question. The simple answer here is that you cannot use multiple `tax_query`'s.

This had me quickly testing the following scenario before I left for work. Just for fun I went and tried to make use of the category parameters with a `tax_query`, but that gave me posts from the desired category and posts that also belongs to both post formats

I came up with a possible solution, unfortunately I cannot test this right now.

**Here is my line of though here:**

As you need random results, I would suggest that you add your post formats into an array

```
$post_format_array = array( 'post-format-video', 'post-format-image' );
```

You now are going to use [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to shuffle the array, and then take the first entry from that array, which will be either video of image, and use that in your `tax_query`.

```
shuffle( $post_format_array );
```

This way you will get posts that is in your desired category and in either video or image post format.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $catslug,
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $post_format_array[0]
      ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks @Pieter for your response. I have tested your code and it does work perfectly (: